# Iniciar sesion en php usando $_SESSION

Tags: php

Alguien podria ponerme un codigo sencillo de como utilizar la variable global $_SESSION ?

El problema es que al iniciar sesion no se como guardar el usuario en la variable global $_SESSION y como utilizarla posteriormente en las demas paginas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {

    $base = new PDO("pgsql: host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=sistema", "postgres", "123456");

    $base->SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $pg = "select * from usuarios where usuario = :usuario or correo_usuario = :usuario";

    $resultado = $base->prepare($pg);

    $usuario = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['usuario']));

    $clave = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['clave']));

    $resultado->Execute(array(":usuario" => $usuario));

    $registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(password_verify($clave, $registro['clave'])){

            session_start();

            $_SESSION['login']=$registro;
            header("location:cronograma.php");

        }else{

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['error']=$alerta;
            header("location:acceso.php");

        }

 } catch (Exception $e) {

    die("Error: " . $e->GetMessage());

 }
```

Con este código puedes iniciar tu `session_start`, el usuario se esta guardando en `$_SESSION['login']`, para recuperar los datos que necesites de tu usuario logeado tendrias que añadir otro parametro que ya tengas declarado en tu base de datos, por ejemplo, `$_SESSION['login']['id_usuario']`, así recuperas el id del usuario ingresado. Si en tu base de datos tienes `nombre` entonces para el nombre pondrías `$_SESSION['login']['nombre']` el valor que quieras recuperar lo declaras en la segunda dimensión del array.